# Using hashmap to display data in JTextField and update it

Tags: java, swing, hashmap, display, datahandler

Below is code that creates items that have code number name, price and quantity respectively.

```
 public class StockData {
    private static class Item {
        Item(String n, double p, int q) {
            name = n;
            price = p;
            quantity = q;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
        public int getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }
        private final String name;
        private final double price;
        private int quantity;
    }
    public final static Map<String, Item> stock = new HashMap();
    static {
        stock.put("00", new Item("Bath towel", 5.50, 10));
        stock.put("11", new Item("Plebney light", 20.00, 5));
        stock.put("22", new Item("Gorilla suit", 30.00, 7));
        stock.put("33", new Item("Whizz games console", 50.00, 8));
        stock.put("44", new Item("Oven", 200.00, 4));
    }
    public static Map<String, Item> getStock() {
       return stock;
     }
    public static String getName(String key) {
        Item item = stock.get(key);
        if (item == null) {
            return null; // null means no such item
        } else {
            return item.getName();
        }
    }
    public static double getPrice(String key) {
        Item item = stock.get(key);
        if (item == null) {
            return -1.0; // negative price means no such item
        } else {
            return item.getPrice();
        }
    }
    public static int getQuantity(String key) {
        Item item = stock.get(key);
        if (item == null) {
            return -1; // negative quantity means no such item
        } else {
            return item.getQuantity();
        }
    }

    public static void update(String key, int extra) {
        Item item = stock.get(key);
        if (item != null) {
            item.quantity += extra;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a different class that is a part of my gui which looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ7R5.jpg

and my idea is you type the code of an item eg. 22 then type how many you would like to add to the stock so for example 5 you click add so it adds to the variable but immidiately updates the text in the box as you can see on the screen.

I really got myself puzzled with hashmap / list I don't think there is a point copying all the data from hashmap to list and pretty much multiplying it there must be a better way to achieve this.

```
public class UpdateStock extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JTextField stockNo = new JTextField(4);
JButton addButton = new JButton("ADD");
JSpinner quantitySlider = new JSpinner();
JTextArea catalog = new JTextArea(7, 30);
List items = new ArrayList();

public UpdateStock(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 500);
    setTitle("Update Stock");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel top = new JPanel();
    add("North", top);
    JPanel middle = new JPanel();
    add("Center", middle);

    top.add(stockNo);
    top.add(quantitySlider);
    top.add(addButton);

    catalog.setLineWrap(true);
    catalog.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    catalog.setEditable(false);
    middle.add(new JScrollPane(catalog));
    for(String key : StockData.getStock().keySet()) {
        catalog.append("Item: " + key +"\n");
        items.add(StockData.getName(key));
        catalog.append("Name: " + StockData.getName(key) +
                "  Price: " + StockData.getPrice(key) +
                " Qty: " + StockData.getQuantity(key)+"\n");
    }
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Didn't I post a fully working example on your other post?

Comment: @JayC667 I've seen that example it is way overcomplicated for me to understand or get through and I don't see a point of using a list copying data from a hashmap to a list and doubling the amount of memory required to store it

Comment: Well... uh... it actually just takes 4 bytes more for every *object reference* because the actual object is not getting copied. And yes, it's quite large, but it's a really clean and easily extensible example. And it's the basic idea to have two different lists of items, because stock and cart **HAPPEN TO BE** two completely different lists with different *PURPOSE*. Don't worry about memory size there, you could have at least a million such objects in the app and not have any memory problems.

Comment: @JayC667 but still I would like to have the simplest possible solution so I can actually understand it

Answer (score 1):

your code immediately puts text in the `JTextArea` because you tell it to.  It's right there in the constructor:

```
for(String key : StockData.getStock().keySet()) {
    catalog.append("Item: " + key +"\n");
    items.add(StockData.getName(key));
    catalog.append("Name: " + StockData.getName(key) +
            "  Price: " + StockData.getPrice(key) +
            " Qty: " + StockData.getQuantity(key)+"\n");
}
```

If you want to wait until the user picks an item before setting any text, then register an `ActionListener` on `addButton` using its `addActionListener()` method.  Use that listener's `actionPerformed()` method to set the text.  Don't forget to remove the code shown above from your constructor, too.

I see you already know about the `ActionListener` class, since it's implemented by `UpdateStock`, but it's a little weird (though totally valid!) to do it that way; I don't think I've seen many subclasses of `JFrame` implement it directly.  The usual pattern is to use an [anonymous `ActionListener`](http://www.leepoint.net/GUI/events/anonymous_listener.html) and just register that instead.  If you really want to use `UpdateStock` as an `ActionListener`, then you'll need an `actionPerformed()` method defined in `UpdateStock` and you'll need to register `this` as an action listener on your button.

Comment: I want it to be displayed immidiately like it is now so Gorrila Suit is Quantity is 7 so somebody types 22 (the code for gorilla suit) then 2 and clicks add and I want the JTextArea to get updated immidiately and show 9 instead of 7 that's my problem i don't know how to change just this value